# XAMPP Version v3.1.0.3.1.0 gets crashed every time when click on apache start button

Tags: windows-7, xampp

I have new xampp installed in my windows 7 pc, so that i get the latest version of PHP to run zendframework2 application.

But some times my xampp gets crashed when i click on stop ->start button (to restart) after some changes in the configuration.

I have taken care of ports. But i think this version of xampp is not working.
refered this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276207/xampp-does-not-start-in-windows-7

Please suggest me any other version of xampp to work properly.

Comment: check apaches error log and you'll find the error

Comment: @Sam, i am getting 'Access Violation at address 005ABEFE in module xampp-control.exe'... in the empty space in xampp.
in apache error log it is empty

Comment: uninstall, re-download the current stable installer, and go again. Should be good to go, probably just a corrupt installation

Comment: @Thanks Sam, i did like, as you said, downloaded the new xampp, and it works fine. cheers